# What is the average value of the square of the maximum of a normalized vector?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, spheres

Consider a normalized vector $\textbf{v}$ of length $N$, that therefore belongs to the surface of an $N$-sphere. Take now the maximum of the absolute value of the vector. For example for $N$=2, this function is $\max(|\cos(\theta)|,|\sin(\theta)|)$. Consider now the square of this value. Is there a smart way to calculate the average of this value over the $N$-sphere? I can do it for $N$=2 and it equals $\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+1}{\pi}$ but in general it seems challenging. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function that you want to average is not spherically symmetric and hence there is no reason to think that the answer would be something "nice" and the complexity will obviously increase as the dimension increases. For example, in $1D$, you just have $\frac{1}{\pi/4}\cdot\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos^{2}(\theta)\,d\theta$ (It suffices to consider the first octant arc). However, I admit that I do not know whether there is some trick to actually solve the integrals and give a nice closed form.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thanks for the comment. I think you are right. We could however exploit the spherical symmetry and just calculate the integral in a limited section of the hyper-sphere, since the result should be then an integer multiple of this (depending on the amount of variables), as you mentioned for the 2D (1 parameter ) case. I think a similar but of course more general approach could work for higher dimensions. I ask this because this result is closely related to the non-sparsity of a vector. Are you able to solve the problem for N=3?